# Hadoop read files with following name patterns

Tags: hadoop

This may sound very basic but I have a folder in HDFS with 3 kinds of files.
eg:

access-02171990

s3.Log

catalina.out

I want my map/reduce to read only files which begin with access- only. How do I do that via program? or specifying via the input directory path? 
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the input path as a glob:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(jobConf, new Path("/your/path/access*"))
```